# Add static route with Ansible

Tags: networking, routing, ansible

How do I add and delete routes in my route table with Ansible?

I can't seem to find any [network](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/list_of_network_modules.html) or [system](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/list_of_system_modules.html) modules for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK, you're stuck using the [command](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/command_module.html) module to make your change using a shell command.

Comment: The link is broken!!!

Answer (score 2):

[net_static_route](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/module_docs/net_static_route_module.html) is available since ansible 2.4.

Depending on your requirements it might provide what you need.

Comment: Just in case: this module is for network appliances and not for linux boxes.