# Add Static Route on Linux with Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I would like to know if there's a module I can use to manage static routes on a Linux device (Ubuntu 18.04)

I have found this question: [Add static route with Ansible](https://serverfault.com/questions/742019/add-static-route-with-ansible)

but this was asked almost 4 years ago and ansible has moved forward since then so thought it was worth asking again, or am I still restricted to bash CLI?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As before, Ansible modules specifically for routing exist for network gear and Windows boxes.

As usual when a task specific module does not exist, the general pattern is to template out a config file. In this case, for netplan.